# Authentication error while copying a file from subversion directory to a location in unix server using curl

Tags: svn, unix, curl, ssl

I want to copy a file from subversion repository to a location in unix box. I am using the following command

```
curl -o /opt/somedirectory/abc.properties https://svn_repo/abc.properties
```

It gives me a SSL certificate problem

*curl: (60) SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html*

I even tried with some authentication inputs with a --insecure option but still gives me the same issue.

```
curl --user username:password -o /opt/somedirectory/abc.properties https://svn_repo/abc.properties --insecure
```

Can someone help me in this topic as to if this is possible using curl or are there any other means to do the same.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `curl -k -o` The -k will help to override the curl ssl security. Alternately you can use `svn export` to get files from remote svn to your local machine.

```
svn export https://svn_repo/abc.properties /opt/somedirectory/ --username someuser --password somepassword
```

Comment: -k doesn't work, still getting the SSH exception. The place where i am copying the file doesn't have subversion.

Comment: `curl --user username:password -o /opt/somedirectory/abc.properties https://svn_repo/abc.properties --insecure` This command itself is working fine for me. In case svn is not installed, you can try wget also to get the file from SVN. `wget --user=yourusername --ask-password -m -np --no-check-certificate https://svn_repo/abc.properties' this will ask you to enter the password, instead you can mention --password option also.